# jQuery .html and razor exception

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here I have a partial view, and I try to insert another partial view into div#Comments than Google Chrome casts exception

```
@{
  Layout = null;
  var data = Html.Partial("Partial/Comments", Model).ToHtmlString();
}
<script>
var c = $("#Comments");
c.empty();@
c.html("@data"); // here is exception
</script>
```

Here is code rendered in data

```
<form action="/Quest/Comment" class="form-horizontal" id="CommentAddForm" method="post">            <fieldset>
            <input id="qid" name="qid" type="hidden" value="11" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="body" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            <div><input id="body" name="body" type="text" value="write here" /></div>


            </fieldset>
</form>        <button id="CommentAdd">
                        Add Comment
                    </button>
```

This partial works fine in other parts of my project, but here I have a trouble.
What should I do than?

**UPDATED**
Here is code catched by google chrome debugger

```
  <div ></div>
  success    <script>
  var c = $("#Comments");
  c.empty();
  c.html("
  &lt;form action=&quot;/Quest/Comment&quot; class=&quot;form-horizontal&quot;id=&quot;CommentAddForm&quot; method=&quot;post&quot;&gt;            &lt;fieldset&gt;
  &lt;input id=&quot;qid&quot; name=&quot;qid&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot;value=&quot;11&quot; /&gt;
            &lt;span class=&quot;field-validation-valid&quot; data-valmsg-for=&quot;body&quot; data-valmsg-replace=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
        &lt;div&gt; &lt;input id=&quot;body&quot; name=&quot;body&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; value=&quot;write here&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/fieldset&gt;
 &lt;/form&gt;        &lt;button id=&quot;CommentAdd&quot;&gt;
                    Add Comment
                &lt;/button&gt;
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: Google Chrome says nothing, just cancels the debuggering. But FireBug catches this exception
`SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
c.html("
`

Comment: try encoding the html using @httputility.htmlencode(data).. or specifical .. @httputility.javascriptencode

Comment: With `@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(data)` I get error `SyntaxError: syntax error
&amp;lt;form action=&amp;quot;/Quest/Comment&amp;quot; class`
However `@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(data)` injects my html, but multipy all quotes, so I have bad html like this `<form id=""CommentAddForm"" class=""form-horizontal"" method=""post"" action=""/Quest/Comment"">`

Comment: Do you see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting arbitrary text into a Javascript string literal.
If that text happens to contain special characters (quotes or newlines or backslashes), it won't be a valid string literal.
This is giving you a Javascript syntax error.

Razor is making it slightly worse by HTML-encoding the text too.

You need to *Javascript*-encode the text so that it will always be a valid string literal.
You can do this by calling `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()`.

You also need to prevent Razor from HTML-escaping the resulting text (since Javascript source code is not HTML), by calling `Html.Raw()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 c.html('@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(data)');
```

However, you might run into multi-line issues. You can try loading in the partial view via AJAX instead:

```
 c.load('@Url.Content("Partial/Comments")');
```

Comment: HtmlDecode only gets two parameters and doesnt return any string. 
Moreover @Url.Content("Partial/Comments") dosnt use my view with model I send here `Html.Partial("Partial/Comments", Model)`

Comment: HtmlDecode has this overload where it takes a single string and returns a string: `public static string HtmlDecode(string s)`. I did miss passing the model to the partial view... Did you just need the question ID? We have other ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Actually, give SLaks answer a whirl, his answer is simpler.

Comment: `HtmlDecode` is not at all relevant here; it's getting encoded by Razor after evaluating the expression.  And that wouldn't help anyway.